# Empty entries- Custom Field Set w/ multiple records

Tags: multiple-records

I have a custom field set ("visits") that allows multiple records.

For some contacts there are multiple empty "visit" records. The number isn't consistent, so I'm wondering if these are being generated by specific actions?

I'd like to know how to stop the empty records from being created.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you pls update your Question to explain if the custom field is in use on Profiles via the front end, or is only used via the backend. also is this field on Contacts, or Participants or Activities

Comment: The field set is used both in a front-end form and in the backend